# My JavaScript in Acrobat is running, most of the time

Tags: javascript, date, adobe, acrobat

I wrote a JavaScript to calculate the amount of days between two dates including start and end date.
This script also subtracts weekends and holidays.

I tried it on JSFiddle and it worked well. It is probably not the fastest or most versatile solution but it works for my purposes.

When I tried running it in Acrobat it first didn't work at all but with Acrobat 64bit it runs.
Still not perfect but it works.

I was wondering if someone had the time to take a look and maybe give me some info on why it only works in certain conditions.

**Code:**

```
var StartDate = this.getField("1").value
var EndDate = this.getField("2").value
//Gets input field value

var StartDate = util.scand("dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS", StartDate + " 00:00:01");
var EndDate = util.scand("dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS", EndDate + " 23:59:59");
//Formatting them to the correct date format

var Saturday = 6;
var Sunday = 7;
//Weekends will have to be defined as the first of the year

var Holiday = [
  14,
  15,
  16
];
//Could improve that but for now the holidays are represented as the number of day in the year

var now = new Date(StartDate);
var start = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
var diff = now - start;
var oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var day = Math.floor(diff / oneDay);
var StartDate = day;

var now = new Date(EndDate);
var start = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
var diff = now - start;
var oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var day = Math.floor(diff / oneDay);
var EndDate = day;
//Converting the start and end dates

var DaysBetween = [];
for (var i = StartDate; i <= EndDate; i++) {
  DaysBetween.push(i);
}
//Array for days in between

var Holidays = 0;
Holiday.forEach((entry) => {
  if (entry >= StartDate & entry <= EndDate) {
    Holidays++;
  }
});
//Checks if holidays fall into this span

var Saturdays = 0;
DaysBetween.forEach((entry) => {
  if (entry % Saturday == 0) {
    Saturdays++;
  }
});

var Sundays = 0;
DaysBetween.forEach((entry) => {
  if (entry % Sunday == 0) {
    Sundays++;
  }
});
//Checks if the days between are a multiple of the first weekend

var DaysAbsent = 0;
DaysAbsent = DaysBetween.length - Holidays - Saturdays - Sundays;

event.value = DaysAbsent;
```

I also have these **error logs:**

TypeError: this.getField(...) is null
3:Field:Calculate
TypeError: this.getField(...) is null
3:Field:Calculate

Comment: Well are the fields there, and are they there before the JS is executed?

Comment: The fields are in the pdf and the script runs when I make a change to the output field (write something in it which starts the script and replaces it with the current calculation)

Comment: Can you do some log output? To see what exactly is null?

Comment: Field 1:
StartDate: 01.01.2021
Field 2:
EndDate: 12.01.2021
Field 1 Formated:
StartDate: 1

No errors, huh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me! I don't know what specifically changed, my guess is the date format in the input field did the trick, but Acrobat accepts it and throws no errors.

```
var StartDate = this.getField("1").value
console.println("StartDate: " + StartDate);
var EndDate = this.getField("2").value
console.println("EndDate: " + EndDate);
//Gets input field value

var StartDate = util.scand("dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS", StartDate + " 00:00:01");
var EndDate = util.scand("dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS", EndDate + " 23:59:59");
//Formatting them to the correct date format

var Saturday = 6;
var Sunday = 7;
//Weekends will have to be defined as the first of the year

var Holiday = [
  01 / 01 / 2021,
  01 / 02 / 2021,
  01 / 03 / 2021
];

//Could improve that but for now the holidays are represented as the number of day in the year

var now = new Date(StartDate);
var start = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
var diff = now - start;
var oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var day = Math.floor(diff / oneDay);
var StartDate = day;
console.println("StartDate: " + StartDate);

var now = new Date(EndDate);
var start = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
var diff = now - start;
var oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var day = Math.floor(diff / oneDay);
var EndDate = day;
//Converting the start and end dates

var DaysBetween = [];
for (var i = StartDate; i <= EndDate; i++) {
  DaysBetween.push(i);
}
//Array for days in between

var Holidays = 0;
Holiday.forEach((entry) => {
  var now = new Date(entry);
  var start = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
  var diff = now - start;
  var oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  var day = Math.floor(diff / oneDay);
  entry = day;
  if (entry >= StartDate & entry <= EndDate) {
    Holidays++;
  }
});
//Checks if holidays fall into this span

var Saturdays = 0;
DaysBetween.forEach((entry) => {
  if (entry % Saturday == 0) {
    Saturdays++;
  }
});

var Sundays = 0;
DaysBetween.forEach((entry) => {
  if (entry % Sunday == 0) {
    Sundays++;
  }
});
//Checks if the days between are a multiple of the first weekend

var DaysAbsent = 0;
DaysAbsent = DaysBetween.length - Holidays - Saturdays - Sundays;

event.value = DaysAbsent;
```

The calculation for saturdays and sundays is still flawed but I am working on a new solution. If you are interested in that solution lmk.